# My website can't handle multiple user authentication at same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js, ejs

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require('express-session');
const _ = require("lodash");
const passport = require("passport");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
const findOrCreate = require('mongoose-findorcreate');


const homeStartingContent = "Lacus vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui id ornare. Semper auctor neque vitae tempus quam. Sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit amet justo. Viverra tellus in hac habitasse. Imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta. Donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales ut. Mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing. Magnis dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies. Adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus. Ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at. Odio euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate odio ut. Cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing.";
const aboutContent = "Hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque. Dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper. Non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed. Platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit. Egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse. Mauris in aliquam sem fringilla. Semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci. Amet massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros. Enim ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui.";
const contactContent = "Scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien. Rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices. Arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique. Risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae. Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis. Iaculis nunc sed augue lacus. Interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Pulvinar elementum integer enim neque. Ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci nulla. Mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt. Tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero.";
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

var profileName="";

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.use(session({
  secret: "This is the secret key",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://paritosh_dalai:Jinu1606@cluster0.mjxiq.mongodb.net/blogDB", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useCreateIndex: true
});

const postSchema = {
  title: String,
  content: String,
  name: String
};

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  password: String,
  googleId: String,
  facebookId: String
});
userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
const Post = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID:process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret:process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "https://murmuring-plains-67934.herokuapp.com/auth/google/blog",
    userProfileURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    profileName=profile.displayName;
    User.findOrCreate({
      googleId: profile.id,
      name: profile.displayName
    }, function(err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }
));

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID:process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    clientSecret:process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "https://murmuring-plains-67934.herokuapp.com/auth/facebook/blog"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    profileName=profile.displayName;
    // console.log(profile);
    User.findOrCreate({
      facebookId: profile.id,
      name: profile.displayName
    }, function (err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }
));


app.get("/auth/google",
  passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ["profile"]
  })
);

app.get("/auth/google/blog",
  passport.authenticate('google', {
    failureRedirect: "/"
  }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect("/blog");
  });

  app.get('/auth/facebook',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: ['public_profile'] }));

  app.get('/auth/facebook/blog',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
    function(req, res) {
      // Successful authentication, redirect home.
      res.redirect('/blog');
    });

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("home");
});


app.get("/blog", function(req, res) {
  Post.find({}, function(err, posts) {
    res.render("blog", {
      startingContent: homeStartingContent,
      posts: posts
    });
  });

});

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  req.logout();
  req.session.destroy();
  res.redirect('/');
});


app.get("/compose", function(req, res) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.render("compose");
  } else {
    res.redirect("/");
  }
});

app.post("/compose", function(req, res) {

  const post = new Post({
    title: req.body.postTitle,
    content: req.body.postBody,
    name: profileName
  });

  post.save(function(err) {
    if (!err) {
      res.redirect("/blog");
    }
  });
});

app.get("/posts/:postId", function(req, res) {
  const requestedPostId = req.params.postId;

  Post.findOne({
    _id: requestedPostId
  }, function(err, post) {
    res.render("post", {
      title: post.title,
      content: post.content,
      name: post.name
    });
  });

});

app.get("/about", function(req, res) {
  res.render("about", {
    aboutContent: aboutContent
  });
});

app.get("/contact", function(req, res) {
  res.render("contact", {
    contactContent: contactContent
  });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

I am creating a website with user authentication but my problem is I have created a var 'profileName' which stores the name of user authenticated to the website but whenever two people authenticates at a period of time, the value of the 'profileName' stores the value of the peron who authenticated later, so for both of the person the value becomes the one who logged in later... How to overcome that, I'm clueless... I know exactly where i'm going wrong but i'm clueless how to solve that

Comment: why are you storing profile name on the server?

Comment: Authentication and security is a solved problem (though of course still evolving over time). The issue you're running into suggests you are trying to reinvent the wheel from scratch, with a beginner's grasp on how to do so. Security isn't the easiest thing to get right as a beginner. It'd be much more efficient to first use an established approach to securely authenticate your users - whether it is to learn the ropes or to not have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I'm creating a blogging website with an authentication, so I want my website to display the user_name with the blogs they post... If you can say any alternative of doing it would be appreciated too

Comment: Did you really just post your whole code including username&passwords hardcoded into your code? Sure, the more complete the example code the best answers but your should **never** hardcode credentials into your code. Access the credentials via environment variable/files on disk... Also the example should be *minimal*, here you are defining 2 different identity providers and multiple endpoints...

Answer (score 0):

store it in your userSchema so that each user gets a different profile name

Comment: I'm storing the name in the userSchema already, but its not working though

Comment: have you tried using the findOne model to find the specific user and then res.send or res.render it to them?